# Modify rhandsontable by modifying another rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have the dataframe below:

```
DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                 car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                 transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
```

I created a shiny app which goal is to modify the 2nd rhandsontable according to the modification of the 1st rhandsontable.More specifically:

1.Initially is displayed the first row of this `DF2` as rhandsontable.

2.Then I modify the cell of the 1st row-1st column by selecting one of the dropdown choices through the rhandsontable.

3.I convert the modified rhandsontable to a dataframe via jsonlite.

4.Then I extract the modified value from this dataframe and subset the initial `DF2` 1st column.

5.Then I display the 1st row of the 2nd rhandsontable which should have displayed the modified dataset but it does not.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
      rHandsontableOutput("hot2")
    )
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(jsonlite)
server <- function(input, output) {

   #Create rhandsontable as a reactive expression
   DFR2<-reactive({
      rhandsontable(DF2[1,1:2], rowHeaders = NULL,width=1400,height = 200)%>%
         hot_col(colnames(DF2)[1])   
   })

   #Display the rhandsontable
   output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({

      DFR2()

   })

   #Convert the rhandsontable to a daraframe
   DFR3<-reactive({
      data_fram <- fromJSON(DFR2()$x$data)
   })
   #Subset the initial dataframe by value of the 1st row-1st column cell of DF3
   DFR4<-reactive({
      newdata <- DF2[ which(DF2[,1]==DFR3()[1,1]), ] 
   })
   #Display the new rhandsontable
   output$hot2 <- renderRHandsontable({

      rhandsontable(DFR4()[1,], rowHeaders = NULL,width=1400,height = 200)%>%
         hot_col(colnames(DFR4()))   


   })



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main solution is that in `DFR3` you should refer to `input$hot` instead of `DFR2()`:

```
DFR3 <- reactive({
  req(input$hot)
  hot_to_r(input$hot)
})
```

Use the `%in%` operator as `hot_to_r` returns ordered factors that can't be compared with normal factors using the `==` operator. (alternatively define `DF2$agency_postcode` as an ordered factor)

```
DFR4 <- reactive({
  req(DFR3())
  DF2[ which(DF2[,1] %in% DFR3()[1, 1]), ]
})
```

#### Output:

[image: output]